# To sum arrays and get the final large value of pixel == 1, others values == 0

Tags: python, numpy

I am new in python syntax.

I want to sum 5 arrays (boolean, have value of pixels 1 or 0)  and put the the final large value of `pixel(5) ==  1`, others `values == 0`.

```
resArraySum = np.array(5, (first | second | third | fourth | fifth), 1, 0)
print resArraySum
```

This is not correct.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want to take five arrays and count the number of times 1 appears in any of the arrays? Then what does "others `values == 0` mean?

Comment: Yes,  first  I want to  sum   5 arrays. Each array (raster with pixels which value can be 1 or 0).   Then   if sum array's pixels  met all 1 from rasters(arrays) - the max value of these pixels = 5,      want to  give these pixels  1,  all other pixels with value 4, 3, 2, 1    value  0.

Comment: What are you getting when you do it this way and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: I expect  pixels with  value 5 (after sum), give  1.  But  syntaxis is wrong.

Comment: Read the traceback.  It probably tells you exactly what's wrong... or at worst, points to the line immediately after the problem.  If it doesn't, [edit] your question to include the _full_ traceback.

Comment: Also, are you using Python 2 or 3?  That `print` command would indeed be a syntax error in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did understood properly, you want to add 5 arrays and then create a mask where the pixels sum 5. I see here some miss-concepts that have nothing to do with python and its syntax.

First, booleans in python are defined as `True` and `False`, `0` and `1` are just integers with no boolean property (not entirely true if you compare them bitewise, but lets just leave this for now).

Second, what you are looking for is just the `logical and` operator, summing 5 arrays of 0 and 1 and then finding the indexes that sum to 5 is a bit overhead, you could just directly compare them logically.

The pseudo-code would look like this:

- For small number of masks:

  ```
  result = bool_mask[0] & bool_mask[1] & bool_mask[2] & bool_mask[3]
  ```
- For a large number of masks:

  ```
  # bool_mask = [a, b, c, d, e, f....] number of boolean arrays
  result = bool_mask[0]         # Equivalent to:
  for mask in bool_mask[1:]:    # for i in range(1, len(bool_mask)):
      result &= mask            #     result &= bool_mask[i]
  ```

With `N` the number of masks and `bool_mask` a list containing the `boolean arrays` that you want to compare.

So, the first thing you have to do, is to properly create a boolean array. With numpy you can do that in a variety of different ways:

- Creating it:

  ```
  >>> A = np.array([1, 0, 1], dtype=np.bool) # will cast 1 to True and 0 to False
  >>> A
  array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
  ```
- Converting it:

  ```
  >>> A = np.array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int) # An integer array with 0 and 1
  >>> A = A.astype(np.bool)
  >>> A
  array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
  ```
- Comparing it:

  ```
  >>> A = np.array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int) # Same int array
  >>> A = A > 0.5
  >>> A
  array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
  ```

After you have your *boolean arrays* made truly boolean, either any of the *pseudocode* (it is real working code tho) above would work just fine.

Afterwards, if you will end up with an array `result` of type `np.bool` (boolean) with `True` values where all the masks intersect and `False` elsewhere. If you really want to go back to the `0` and `1` values, you could just cast the result down:

```
result = result.astype(int)
```

And `True` will be mapped to `1` while `False` to `0`. Other ways of doing similar things would be:

```
result = result * 1
```

Any kind of numerical operations in numpy will cast a boolean array to integers.

Now, you will find (as mentioned above), that although `1` and `0` arrays are not *boolean* arrays, same and `&` operator will make bite-wise comparisons that would end up behaving like boolean arrays (as long as they only contain `1` and `0` values). Thus,

```
result = a & b & c & d
```

would work for both `integer` (with only `1` and `0`) and `boolean` arrays. However, I would suggest using boolean arrays whether possible, as many interesting features of numpy such as [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) only work if the arrays are truly boolean (an integer array of `0` and `1` would behave very differently that what you would expect).